# How to deploy ff4j server in AKS?

Tags: deployment, azure-aks, ff4j

I have created ff4j server with name - "ff4j-feature-toggle-server" as a maven java project. Trying to deploy this on AKS. I get the below in my logs -

**"no main manifest attribute, in ff4j-feature-toggle-server.jar"**

I have checked my deployment files and the name is correct and the server runs perfectly in my local machine - but I am unable to deploy on AKS. Can't find anything online regarding ff4j aks deployment as well.

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No error were mentioned to the ff4j team before regarding AKS deployments. ASK expect an executable JAR i guess.

You might get this error when Main-Class entry is missing in MANIFEST.MF file. You can put maven-jar-plugin plugin in pom.xml to fix it.

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>org.yourapp.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

source:https://java2blog.com/no-main-manifest-attribute/